# Queuing timed jquery events not working properly

Tags: css, jquery, jquery-effects

So I have an empty div set to display:none called id="c1".

I am trying to queue it so that it will fade in and will say:
2 seconds

then after 1 second it will say:
1 second

then will fade out and the page redirects.

```
$('#c1').html('2 seconds').fadeIn('fast').delay(800).html('1 second').delay(800).fadeOut('fast');
```

However, when I run it, I only see "1 second" and it fades out. I cannot see the 2 seconds message at all. It's like as if jquery only listens to the last "html" event.

I have also tried just entering "2 seconds" in the div as default text in html. That doesn't work either. still says "1 second" as soon as the page loads.

**EDIT SOLUTION**

You can do something like this:

```
$('#c1').html('2').fadeIn('fast').delay(800).queue(function () {$(this).html('1');$(this).dequeue();}).delay(800).fadeOut('fast');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only delay() animations, not other functions like html(), they are perfomered instantly.

Use a timeout for the html() functions instead, or place them in the animation callback.

```
$('#c1').html('2 seconds').fadeIn(1000, function() {
   $(this).html('1 second').fadeOut(1000);
});​
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out after I posted. Or I can use queues.

Comment: Yes, custom queues, like using jQuery's queue() and dequeue() will also work.

Comment: Yep I posted a solution code that works great! But I will still give you best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $('#c1').html('2 seconds')fadeIn('fast');
    setTimeout($('#c1').html('1     second'), 800);
    setTimeout($('#c1').fadeOut('fast'), 800);
```

Comment: Yeah setTimeouts can work too, or custom queues or the way adeneo did it.

Comment: Actually it does'nt work like that, there's a period missing before the first fadeIn(), and you need function calls in those timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Right, the doc states: "It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue", but the operations like .html() are not using the effects queue...